# Stationary on a geodesic

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram, geodesics, equivalence-principle

If the Earth were not spinning or orbiting the Sun would we still feel gravity?

I ask because it seems to me that in that case we would not be accelerating and we would still be standing on a geodesic and not crossing it.

Comment: If Earth were extremely far away from the Sun and the geodesic were oriented purely in the time direction, in which direction would it curve? Still towards the Sun?

Answer (score 2):

The earth’s orbit around the sun is a geodesic in spacetime. It is decidedly not a geodesic in space. You cannot stand still on a geodesic in spacetime, the most that you can do is to have your geodesic oriented purely in the “time” direction. Such geodesics still curve inward towards the sun.

Answer (score 0):

> If the Earth were not spinning or orbiting the Sun would we still feel
> gravity?

I understood that you mean the gravity from the Earth on us.

A geodesic is a trajectory joining 2 points. In the surface of the earth for example, for coordinates longitudes and latitudes, a geodesic between 2 cities is part of a grand circle joining them. That means that if both have the same latitude, a naive route following west (or east) is not a geodesic (except in equator). In spite of being "stationary" in the meaning of conserving all the time the same latitude.

In spacetime, considering one coordinate time and one space (the height above ground for example), a geodesic is a trajectory between 2 events. Similar to the previous example, keeping the same height all the time is not a geodesic. Being in free fall is (like travelling through a great circle in the previous example) a geodesic.